# SVG tag image not seen Android webview

Tags: android, svg, webview, xhtml

i'am using android `WebView` to show xhtml files in my app
for display images i am using `shouldInterceptRequest` function but when i try to use code below

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1478 2544" width="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image width="1478" height="2544" xlink:href="../Images/Antropoloji_Kapak_on_renk.jpg"></image>
</svg>
```

`shouldInterceptRequest` method not called and image could not shown

iam supporting all versions of android 4+

i can't change the content. 
I should display exactly what i have given

-edit-

it turns out when i gave size of image smaller than screen it shows it

but still i want to show it even if it is bigger than screen size

Comment: Which version of the android platform are you running this on?

Comment: i tested it on android 4.1

Comment: SVG should be supported in 4+, although I'm not certain if the loads for sub elements like this are sent through shouldInterceptRequest (I would have thought they would be though). Are you sure that the image exists? Can you try some other more basic SVG elements to see if they are drawn at all?

Comment: i am sure that image exist because same file works on iOS version of my app which also i wrote

Comment: Is this loaded locally via a file:// URL or from a remote server?

Comment: this file is locally added. I using `shouldInterceptRequest` to return response. this method works on img tags and fonts

Answer (score 0):

I use following html page to display your svg:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 3288 2188" width="100%"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <image width="3288" height="2188"
            xlink:href="file:///android_asset/image.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

To display embedded image into svg you should use path with `file:///android_asset/` prefix. If you want to embed image from another location then assets folder, you also should use `file:///` prefix.

Comment: i can't change the content. I should display exactly what i have given

Comment: Main mistake in your svg is that you uses relative file path instead of absolute. Just use file:///android_asset/image.jpg. In fact you need to use uri in href attr of svg.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't change response from server?

This case you can wrap `<svg>` tag with necessary `<html>` and `<body>`

Try this:

```
String svgContent = ... // Your code of svg here
String pageContent = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'></head><body>" + svgContent + "</body></html>";
webview.loadData(pageContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: did you really think it is not in a html page ?